# Drupal 7 Commerce - How do you style the Please wait loading message/icon when you select an attribute?

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

I'm trying to style the please wait loader icon when you select an attribute for a product in drupal 7 commerce. I'm using chrome and i can't figure out a way to right click inspect element fast enough as it loads to fast. Or is there another way to expose this? I just need the HTML and classes associated with it.

[image]

Comment: Aha! i got it to show up by unplugging my internet connection so it throws an error. Here it is: http://prntscr.com/2131ny .. what we're looking for was: .ajax-progress .ajax-progress-throbber

Comment: Note that this is simply the Drupal core AJAX throbber, not specific to Commerce itself.

Comment: oh yes thats true.. its everywhere on the site. its annoying how it breaks the styling when it shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
/* Custom ajax throbber style */
.ajax-progress .throbber {
  /* New icon */
  background: transparent url(../images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  /* icon is 15px square */
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  /* Alignment, may tweak to suit */
  float: left; /* LTR */
  clear:both;
  margin: 2px 2px 8px 2px;
}
.ajax-progress-throbber .message {
  /* Hide the "please wait" msg */
  display: none;
}
```